# The usage of function cutPoints

Tags: partitioning, dolphindb

The usage of function cutPoints in Dolphindb

I used the function cutPoints in the below statements:

```
symbols = array(SYMBOL, 0, 100)
symbols = symbols.distinct().sort!().append!("999999");
symRanges = symbols.cutPoints(100)
```

But the error occurred:

```
binNum is larger than the number of data points.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, [cutPoints](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/cutPoints.html) is used to distribute elements within a number of buckets and it will return a vector. This function can also be used to get the partition scheme of a range domain in a distributed database.

The symbols written in your script contain only one element, so the error is raised because the element cannot be divided into 100 ranges.